# Create samples with different range and weights

Tags: r

I want to create a total sample of 3000 entries with some rules :

```
Category-1(low)  0.1 - 0.3
Category-2(Medium)  0.4 - 0.7
Category-3(High)  0.7 - 0.9
```

I want to create the sample in such a way that each category has weights for example :

```
Category-1(low)  20% of the dataset
Category-2(Medium)  30% of the dataset 
Category-3(High)  50% of the dataset
```

I am unable to find pointers to do that. Can anyone help me out with the same. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try `Map(function(x, y) sample(seq(x, y, by = 0.1), 3000, replace = TRUE), c(0.1, 0.4, 0.7), c(0.3, 0,7, 0.90)`

Comment: Do you have the data already, or do you need to generate data?

Comment: @Paul I need to generate the data

Comment: @akrun How is this handling the weights i.e. 20%, 30% or 50% of the dataset

Comment: Just create that variable `n` also in the sample

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to create a `seq`uence of values between the ranges showed in the OP's post, while generating the `sample` on the ranges with the proportion also being passed in as argument to `Map`

```
lst1 <- Map(function(x, y, z) sample(seq(x, y, by = 0.1), z, 
  replace = TRUE), c(0.1, 0.4, 0.7), c(0.3, 0.7, 0.9), c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5) * 3000)
names(lst1) <- c("low", "medium", "high")
lengths(lst1)
#   low medium   high 
#   600    900   1500 

out <- unlist(lst1)
length(out)
#[1] 3000
```

---

If we need as a two column data.frame

```
dat <- stack(lst1)[2:1]
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You'd get only 20% from the 2nd category.

Comment: @Suren `c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5) * 3000#[1]  600  900 1500` is the calculation

Comment: values I used are based on the OP's post.  i leave it to the OP to make the necessary changes for those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the `simstudy` package for data generation. In this case I back-filled your values that conform to category rules. Simstudy gives a data.table object, but I'm more familiar with Tidyverse syntax:

```
library(simstudy)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1724)

# define data
def <- defData(varname = "category", formula = "0.2;0.3;0.5", dist = "categorical", id = "id")
def <- defData(def, varname = "value", dist = "nonrandom", formula = NA)

# generate data
df <- genData(3000, def) %>% as_tibble()

# add in values that conform to category rules
df[df$category == 1,]$value <- runif(nrow(df[df$category == 1,]), min = 0.1, max = 0.3)
df[df$category == 2,]$value <- runif(nrow(df[df$category == 2,]), min = 0.4, max = 0.7)
df[df$category == 3,]$value <- runif(nrow(df[df$category == 3,]), min = 0.7, max = 0.9)

# A tibble: 3,000 x 3
      id category value
   <int>    <int> <dbl>
 1     1        3 0.769
 2     2        2 0.691
 3     3        3 0.827
 4     4        3 0.729
 5     5        2 0.474
 6     6        3 0.818
 7     7        2 0.635
 8     8        2 0.552
 9     9        3 0.794
10    10        3 0.792
# ... with 2,990 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple approach:

**1.** This is not that random, but depending on the application this may suffice

```
out <- c(runif(600, 0.1, 0.3), runif(900, 0.4, 0.7), runif(1500, 0.7, 0.9))
```

**2.**  Here, you'd draw the numbers coming from each category as well: so more random...

```
sam <- sample(1:3, size = 3000, prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5), replace = TRUE)
x1 <- sum(sam == 1)
x2 <- sum(sam == 2)
x3 <- sum(sam == 3)

out <- c(runif(x1, 0.1, 0.3), runif(x2, 0.4, 0.7), runif(x3, 0.7, 0.9))
```